# How is it possible to find out the HDMI version on windows?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, hdmi, gpu, amd-graphics-card

I would like to know, if my laptop can output 4K/60Hz to the TV, using the HDMI cable. Unfortunately I have no idea where to find this out.

I've found some similar questions, but the answers were not generic, they just answered it for that specific computer.

My laptop is: HP Notebook - 15-ay108nh

The CPU is i5-7200U, which has HDMI 1.4 (4K 24Hz ?), but it shuld be able to output 4K 60Hz on the display port.

The GPU is: AMD Radeon™ R7 M440 Graphics (4 GB DDR3 dedicated). I was not able to find out, what kind of HDMI output does that have.

The laptop has only one HDMI output, but I don't know if it belongs to the integrated or dedicated GPU.

Comment: As for the Radeon " This device has no display connectivity, as it is not designed to have monitors connected to it."...https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-r7-m440.c2851

Comment: HDMI version is determined by what the graphics processor supports, and the R7 M440 is
[said](https://technical.city/en/video/Radeon-RX-540-vs-Radeon-R7-M440)
to be capable of HDMI 2.0.

Comment: @harrymc Where did you read, that "R7 M440 capable of HDMI 2.0"? I am not able to find it on that page. It only states that RX 540 is capable of HDMI 2

Comment: You are absolutely right - I inverted the columns. Actually it says that M440 is *not* capable of HDMI 2.0, and even later on under "Advantages of AMD Radeon RX 540" it lists HDMI 2.0 as one of the advantages.

Comment: Additionally, just because the HDMI 1.4 specification is _able to support_ 4k at up to 30Hz, doesn't mean that your laptop / hardware can actually do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article
[AMD Radeon RX 540 vs R7 M440](https://technical.city/en/video/Radeon-RX-540-vs-Radeon-R7-M440)
says that the M440 does not support HDMI 2.0, and in the section of
"Advantages of AMD Radeon RX 540" it also lists HDMI 2.0 as one of the advantages
of the RX540 over the M440.

Your CPU is i5-7200U, which you have already found out that it is only
capable of HDMI 1.4.

The unfortunate conclusion is that your computer can only do HDMI 1.4.
This does not mean that it cannot do 4K, but just not at 60Hz.
It might be capable of doing 30 Hz or a bit less.

For viewing movies this might still be enough, and for many games as well.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any method to ask the OS about what version the graphics card ports are.

If there is a way to find out, it is somewhere in the graphics driver (but the closest thing I've ever personally come to seeing is the PCIE version...) I'm not on windows nor do I have a radeon graphics card so I can't test this. Additionally, you are in a peculiar situation where you have an integrated and dedicated graphics card.

Usually the method I use to figure out if my graphic card ports are capable of meeting certain standards is to read up on the graphics card on a desktop; but for a laptop I'm afraid there are too many factors that come into play so the only way to know is to read the specs of your specific laptop models.

In your case, your integrated graphics card is capable of 4k@60hz, but only via display port, not hdmi. Whether or not your dedicated GPU supports this is unknown, I cannot find any data on it either (but this strongly implies that it actually can't, because AMD would probably mention it if it could), and whether or not it can actually do it still also ends up being determined by your laptop, because the laptop manufacturer decides whether they put a 1.4 hdmi port or 2.0 hdmi port on the motherboard and [HP does not say which it is](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/c05387252#AbT0).

I'm afraid the most likely conclusion, since no data on hdmi 2 support can be found for your laptop beyond that your integrated graphics do not support it; is that your laptop does not support it either.

If it's any consolation; using a 4K display with such low end hardware is a terrible idea; the 60hz wouldn't do you much good. You're not gonna be doing 4K gaming with such specs, you wouldn't even be able to run minecraft at 4k/60fps with your hardware.